# BigInteger.valueOf() limits

Tags: java, biginteger

Does valueOf for BigInteger have any limitations ? I'm not sure but read somewhere, that given number can be of length = long only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `BigInteger` class itself is used to represent immutable arbitrary-precision integers. Meaning it can represent integers of any size (limited of course by the memory on your computer).

However the `valueOf` method returns a `BigInteger` whose value is equal to that of the specified long. So a `BigInteger` created in this way by definition can only be a large as `Long.MAX_VALUE`

`BigInteger` objects created by the other [methods and constructors](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) of the `BigInteger` class can of course be larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Take for example the code snipped below:

```
BigInteger big1 = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);
BigInteger big2 = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);
BigInteger big3 = big1.add(big2);
```

The `BigInteger` named `big3` is larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE` even though its constituent parts were created using the `valueOf` method.

Answer (score 2):

`BigInteger`'s `valueOf()` method thakes a `long` as its sole parameter. So the maximum number you can pass to it is the maximum a `long` can represent (`2^63-1 = 9223372036854775807`).

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Java API Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) for the [`BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class, the [`BigInteger.valueOf`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf(long)) method takes a `long` as the argument, so the largest number that can be obtained through the `BigInteger.valueOf` method is [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) which is 2^63 - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `BigInteger(String val, int radix)` constructor.  That can create a `BigInteger` of any size.